# Can I increase a number by a macro in LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: libreoffice, basic, libreoffice-impress

I want to make a counter with Libreoffice Impress.

Each Time I click on a rectangle, the number inside increases.

```
Dim Doc As Object
Dim Page As Object 
Dim Rect As Object 

Doc = ThisComponent
Page = Doc.drawPages.getByName("Test")
Rect = Page.getByIndex(0)


Rect.String = CInt(Rect.String) + 1
```

It works everywhere except in presentation mode.

Is it possible to make it work in presentation mode ?